# clear an upstream task in airflow within the dag

Tags: parent-child, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow

i have a task in an airflow DAG. it has three child tasks. unfortunately, there are cases where this parent task will succeed, but two of the three children will fail (and a retry on the children won't fix them).

it requires the parent to retry (even though it didn't fail).

so i dutifully go into the graph view of the dag run and 'clear' this parent task and all downstream tasks (+recursive).

is there a way i can do this within the dag itself?

Answer (score 4):

If your tasks are part of a subdag, calling `dag.clear()` in the `on_retry_callback` of a `SubDagOperator` should do the trick:

```
SubDagOperator(
    subdag=subdag,
    task_id="...",
    on_retry_callback=lambda context: subdag.clear(
        start_date=context['execution_date'],
        end_date=context['execution_date']),
    dag=dag
)
```

Answer (score 3):

We opted for using the `clear_task_instances` method of the `taskinstance`:

```
@provide_session
def clear_tasks_fn(tis,session=None,activate_dag_runs=False,dag=None) -> None:
     """
     Wrapper for `clear_task_instances` to be used in callback function
     (that accepts only `context`)
    """

    taskinstance.clear_task_instances(tis=tis,
                                      session=session,
                                      activate_dag_runs=activate_dag_runs,
                                      dag=dag)

def clear_tasks_callback(context) -> None:
    """
    Clears tasks based on list passed as `task_ids_to_clear` parameter

    To be used as `on_retry_callback`
    """

    all_tasks = context["dag_run"].get_task_instances()
    dag = context["dag"]
    task_ids_to_clear = context["params"].get("task_ids_to_clear", [])

    tasks_to_clear = [ ti for ti in all_tasks if ti.task_id in task_ids_to_clear ]

    clear_tasks_fn(tasks_to_clear,
               dag=dag)
```

You would need to provide the list of tasks you want cleared on the callback, e.g on any child task:

```
DummyOperator('some_child',
              on_retry_callback=clear_tasks_callback,
              params=dict(
                  task_ids_to_clear=['some_child', 'parent']
              ),
              retries=1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar problem which we resolved by putting the task with dependencies that we want to repeat into a sub dag. Then when the sub dag retries we clear the sub dag tasks state using the `on_retry_callback` so that they all run again.

```
sub_dag = SubDagOperator(
    retry_delay=timedelta(seconds=30),
    subdag=create_sub_dag(),
    on_retry_callback=callback_subdag_clear,
    task_id=sub_dag_name,
    dag=dag,
)

def callback_subdag_clear(context):
    """Clears a sub-dag's tasks on retry."""
    dag_id = "{}.{}".format(
        context['dag'].dag_id,
        context['ti'].task_id,
    )
    execution_date = context['execution_date']
    sub_dag = DagBag().get_dag(dag_id)
    sub_dag.clear(
        start_date=execution_date,
        end_date=execution_date,
        only_failed=False,
        only_running=False,
        confirm_prompt=False,
        include_subdags=False
    )
```

(originally taken from here https://gist.github.com/nathairtras/6ce0b0294be8c27d672e2ad52e8f2117)

Answer (score 0):

It does not directly answer your question but I can suggest a better workaround:

```
default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(2017, 12, 16),
    'depends_on_past': True,
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='main_dag',
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    default_args=default_args,
    max_active_runs=1,
    retries=100,
    retry_delay= timedelta(seconds=120)
)
```

Set the `depends_on_past` to True in the DAG.

Then in the tasks of this dag, limit the retries using retries

```
  DummyOperator(
        task_id='bar',
        retries=0
        dag=child)
```

This way the DAG is marked as failed when any task fails. Then the DAG will be retried.

Comment: As far as I can tell this does not work. Based on the documentation depends_on_past will block subsequent task requests until the current task is completed.