# Is it possible to arrange execution of several tasks in a transaction-like mode?

Tags: airflow

By transactional-like I mean - etither all tasks in a set are successful or none of them are and should be retried from the first one.

Consider two operators, `A` and `B`, `A` downloads a file, `B` reads it and performs some actions.

`A` successfully executes, but before `B` comes into play a blackout/corruption occurs, and `B` cannot process the file, so it fails.

To pass, it needs `A` to re-download the file, but since `A` is in `success` status, there is no direct way to do that automatically. A human must go and clear A`s status

Now, if wonder, if there is a known way to clear the statuses of task instances up to a certain task, if some task fails?

I know I can use a hook, as in [clear an upstream task in airflow within the dag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47853270/clear-an-upstream-task-in-airflow-within-the-dag), but that looks a bit ugly

Comment: I don't think this is possible - the [best practices](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#creating-a-task) docs recommend treating *individual* Tasks like transactions, and explicitly suggest *not* allowing Tasks to have partially-complete output.  Following that logic, I think they would probably recommend combining all of this work into a single Task.

Comment: how you wil know that file is corrupted?

Comment: For any structured format I will get error trying to parse it

Comment: @0x5453, such policy will descourage code re-usage and|or motivate to merge operators together yielding exponential number of classes - so I doubt they were talking about this precise case

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported by airflow, but you can use `on_failure_callback` to achieve that:

```py
def clear_task_A(context):
    execution_date = context["execution_date"]
    clear_task_A = BashOperator(
        task_id='clear_task_A',
        bash_command=f'airflow tasks clear -s {execution_date}  -t A -d -y <dag_id>'
    ) # -s: start date, -t: task_id regex -d: include downstream?, -y: yes?
    return clear_task_A.execute(context=context)

with DAG(...) as dag:
    A =  DummyOperator(
        task_id='A'
    )

    B = BashOperator(
        task_id='B',
        bash_command='exit 1',
        on_failure_callback=clear_task_A
    )

    A >> B
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that, that is what essentially in the attached link